# Unexpected Page Reload with Next.js router.push and { shallow: true }

Tags: reactjs, next.js, error-handling, reload

I am encountering an issue in my Next.js application where using router.push with the { shallow: true } option is unexpectedly causing a page reload. That happens only on 404 Next.js Page when I use my redirect hook or just `<Link/>` component. I redirect from "/market/assets" to "/market/finance"

Redirect Hook

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function useRedirect() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (relativePath: string) =>
    router.push(relativePath, undefined, { shallow: true });
}
```

[My files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV2VC.png)

Error404 Next.js page file

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import AppLayout from "@/components/Layout/AppLayout";
import { REDIRECT_404_PATHS } from "@/constants/routes";

export default function Error404() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (REDIRECT_404_PATHS.includes(router.asPath))
      router.push("/", undefined, { shallow: true });
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <AppLayout>
          We can’t find the page you are looking for.
    </AppLayout>
  );
}
```

I tried to:
Changing approach of redirecting doesn't help
Tracking 404 route on  component and just replacing url doesn't help.